# Replace () -> Unit to simple RxJava solution

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I would like to change my `() -> Unit` parameters to Reactive Observer.

For example, I have this class:

```
class ExampleClass {
    var onSuccess: (() -> Unit?)? = null

    private fun doSomething(){
        //...
        onSuccess?.invoke()
        //...
    }
}
```

There is an 'onSuccess' Unit. I call it when it's finished with its' task.

```
fun doAnother(){
    val instance = ExampleClass()
    instance.onSuccess = {
        // onSuccess run
    }

}
```

This is the example of how I define the `onSuccess`.

I'm looking for a **simple** solution with **RxJava** like this.

```
class ExampleClass {
    var onSuccess: AnyMagic

    private fun doSomething(){
        //...
        onSuccess.notify()
        //...
    }
}

fun doAnother(){
    val instance = ExampleClass()
    instance.onSuccess
            .subscribe {
                // RxJava
            }
}
```

Does someone have a good simple solution to replace this Unit?
Thank you

Comment: read about rxjava subjects

Comment: you can implement it and post the solution yourself, I don't have time for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it via RxRelay.

Get the dependency

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.0.0'
```

That's code

```
val myRelay: PublishRelay<String> = PublishRelay.create()

private fun doSomething() {
  myRelay.accept("Hello world")
}

fun doAnother() {
  myRelay.subscribe { s ->
    println(s)
  }
}
```